# Looks like Interaction.Triggers doesn't work with DataContext set

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I will start with my code (entire sample is here: https://github.com/robertwojnar/MvvmDemo1)
In my little demo I have single view application with usercontrol inside. So I have:

1. MainWindow.xaml (my view)
2. FooUserControl.xaml (view of my usercontrol)
3. MainWindowViewModel.cs (viewmodel for my view)

and that's basically it. Very simple. Here is the code:

**FooUserControl.xaml**

```
    <UserControl x:Class="MvvmDemo1.WPF.Views.FooUserControl"
                 xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                 xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
                 xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
                 xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MvvmDemo1.WPF.Views"
                 mc:Ignorable="d" 
                 d:DesignHeight="100" d:DesignWidth="100">
        <Grid MouseDown="UIElement_OnMouseDown">
            <Rectangle Fill="BlueViolet" />
        </Grid>
    </UserControl>
```

**FooUserControl (code-behind)**

```
    public partial class FooUserControl : UserControl
    {
        public FooUserControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }   

        public event EventHandler<BarEventArgs> BarClick;
        private void UIElement_OnMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            double x = e.GetPosition(this).X;
            double y = e.GetPosition(this).Y;
            string value_to_pass = "[" + x + "," + y + "]"; 

            BarEventArgs bar = new BarEventArgs() { Bar = 2, Foo = value_to_pass };
            BarClick?.Invoke(sender, bar);
        }
    }
```

**MainWindow.xaml** (no code behind)

```
    <Window x:Class="MvvmDemo1.WPF.Views.MainWindow"
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
            xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
            xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
            xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MvvmDemo1.WPF.Views"
            mc:Ignorable="d"
            Title="MainWindow" Height="300" Width="300"
            xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
            xmlns:cmd="http://www.galasoft.ch/mvvmlight"
            xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:MvvmDemo1.WPF.ViewModels">
        <Window.DataContext>
            <viewModels:MainWindowViewModel />
        </Window.DataContext>
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="Loaded">
                <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding Mode=OneWay, Path=LoadedCommand}" PassEventArgsToCommand="True" />
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <Grid>
            <local:FooUserControl>
                <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="BarClick">
                        <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding ClickedCommand}" PassEventArgsToCommand="True" />
                    </i:EventTrigger>
                </i:Interaction.Triggers>
            </local:FooUserControl>
        </Grid>
    </Window>
```

**MainWindowViewModel.cs**

```
    public class MainWindowViewModel : ObservableObject
    {
        public string Title => "Main window";

        public ICommand LoadedCommand => new RelayCommand(Loaded);
        private void Loaded()
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Loaded");
        }   

        public ICommand ClickedCommand => new RelayCommand<BarEventArgs>(o => Clicked(o.Foo));
        private void Clicked(string a)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Clicked " + a);
        }
    }
```

As you can see the app is just a purple rectange which (on click event) sends click coordinates to MainWindowViewModel (via ICommand, using MVVM Light's `EventToCommand` and `Interaction.Triggers`).

Here is my problem and question:

I want to add a ViewModel for my UserControl. Want to add `FooUserControlViewModel` to FooUserControl's `DataContext`. The problem is, **ClickedCommand is not fired** when I set DataContext of FooUserControl. The question is **Why?**

When you clone my repo and change FooUserControl (code-behind) constructor to this, you will get my point:

```
    public FooUserControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new FooUserControlViewModel();
    }
```

**EDIT:**
It looks like, MainWindowViewModel is assigned to FooUserControl's DataContext (I think, because `Iteraction.Triggers` or `EventToCommand`). Why is that happening? Isn't this violating the rule that view-viewmodel connection should be 1<->1. One View - one ViewModel?

Comment: Is there any reason you don't just make your controls concrete by using the code-behind as the model? Is there some requirement that you have separated models or do you down the road intend to make them replaceable on the same visual or something? Concrete controls are much simpler and easier to work with and eliminate a lot of the kind of trouble you're seeing here, not sure why so many engineers try to over-complicate MVVM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***If*** you want to assign a new `DatContext` to your `local:FooUserControl` you can do that but you'll no longer will be able to bind your controls from `MainWindowViewModel` directly. You have to change your `Binding` like below for `Command`:

```
<cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}},Path=DataContext.ClickedCommand}" PassEventArgsToCommand="True" />
```

> When we set the `DataContext` of a control it will aotomatically pased
>   down to it's child controls by [Property Value Inheritance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms753197(v=vs.100).aspx). And if
>   you change `DataContext`  of a `UserControl` in middle of a
>   hierarchy/VisualTree the DataContext will be different for `Ancestors`
>   and `Descendants`.

***Also there is no such rule 1 View -1 ViewModel. It's totally depends your design a complexity/ Requirement how many `ViewModels` you have to design for your `View` or one `ViewModel` for different `View`.***